# Is there a way to log the time it takes to acquire connection in hikari?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

Is there a way to log/know the time it takes to acquire a connection in HikariCP within the Springboot application?

I was thinking if there is a way to measure getConnection in hikariCP, any suggestion?

Comment: Would you want to measure it in Code and do something with it or just as a debug notification?

Comment: We have an application that takes a long time to get a DB connection so I'm trying to understand the behavior more, so I want to log it.

Comment: Could you include some of the code that you are looking to profile? If I recall correctly, I think you can populate variables with start/stop times and other counters, then look at these variables in real time with JMX.

Comment: HikariPool-0 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms. Means pool waited 30000ms for free connection but the application not returned any connection meanwhile, so I'm trying ti log and see how long it take to get the connection

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HikariCP collected metrics such as `hikaricp_connections_acquire_seconds` via Prometheus (endpoint /actuator/prometheus if enabled).

Source:
https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/HikariCP-5.0.1/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/metrics/micrometer/MicrometerMetricsTracker.java